# Insert values to fields in iframe on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've built a script that on mouseover iframe inserts values from the parent site into the form fields inside the iframe and it works great on computers.

If I try to run this on a mobile (iPhone 5) it doesn't insert to values. I've tried to do it on button click(on parent site) on the mobile but still no values in the iframes form fields.

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: have you tried in diferent browsers in the iphone? may be its just safari on iphone5

Comment: Tried it now and it doesn't work in chrome either.

Comment: Is the iframe pointing to a different domain? If so, you can't use JavaScript in the parent page to affect the iframe content. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/251420) to trigger a function in an iframe from the parent page.